# Limiting image size when uploading

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a script here that checks files uploaded for size and extension/type. The type check works well but the type check for size does not. Any help please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateImage(fld) {
        if(!/(\.bmp|\.gif|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png)$/i.test(fld.value)) {
            alert("Invalid image file type. Supported image file types: PNG, BMP, JPEG, JPG, GIF");      
            fld.form.reset();
            fld.focus();        
            return false;   
        }   

        if(fld.files[0].size > 2000000) {
            alert("Invalid image file type. Supported image file types: PNG, BMP, JPEG, JPG, GIF");    
            fld.form.reset();
            fld.focus(); 
            return false;
        }
        return true; 
    } 
</script>

<input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" onchange="return validateImage(this);">
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I elaborated enough. Im trying to check for size of file uploaded and if larger than 2MB it should popan alert.

Comment: `validateImage` function in the inline attribute calls `validateFileExtension`? Do you really have `validateImage` function defined?

Comment: So go check what value that property actually has at that point … (debugger/log to console)

Comment: @Perumal93 edited the code. This was a mistake i did when putting the code here. In the actual code, its correct.

Comment: Have you checked the message for the second part. Is the same message for extensions and for file size: "`Invalid image file type...`"

Comment: why was this tagged as php; were you looking to get a php solution? You should, since js can be disabled and they can bypass that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using different function call. Use validateFileExtension() call in onchange event. Or use any other name for both validations.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function validateFileExtension(fld) {
        if(!/(\.bmp|\.gif|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png)$/i.test(fld.value)) {
            alert("Invalid image file type. Supported image file types: PNG, BMP, JPEG, JPG, GIF");      
            fld.form.reset();
            fld.focus();        
            return false;   
        }   

            if(fld.files[0].size > 2097152) {
            alert("Invalid image file type. Supported image file types: PNG, BMP, JPEG, JPG, GIF");    
            fld.form.reset();
            fld.focus(); 
            return false;
        }

        return true; 
     } </script>

    <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" onchange="return validateFileExtension(this);">
```

Comment: This is a typo when i copied here but this doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: 2MB means 2097152

Comment: its not working for me, its not popping an alert. Im testing by uploading a 4MB image.

Comment: @Ali, it is working in Chrome, IE11, Firefox, on Windows. Which browser you use?

Comment: just letting you know, that two alerts can't come at once, because you are returning false after alert

Answer (score 0):

Get follwing code reference, I hope this help you. I think you missed out calculation for file size

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateImage(fld) {
    
        if(fld.files[0].size > (1*1024*1024)) {
        alert("File size must be less than 1 MB");    
        fld.form.reset();
        fld.focus(); 
        return false;
    }

    return true; 
 }  
</script>

<input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" onchange="return validateImage(this);">
```